How to use a CC1101 Module on a DZ-Delivery D1 mini ESP8266MOD 12-F
I recently bought a DZ-Delivery D1 mini ESP8266MOD 12-F microcontroller and a cc1101 868mhz radio module. Now I'm trying to get it to work and failing.
I am using the Easy IoT with CC1101 - Sub-1GHz LORA-like library from Faptastic.
Here I have tried different examples with and without GDO1 /2 but it never works.
Has anyone ever tried this combination of radio module and microcontroller and has running example code for me?
My guess is that the pins in the library are not correct, so not suitable for the specific microcontroller. But I don't know exactly how I can adapt to this.
I tried different examples from the library. I also asked ChatGPT for an example program. But none of them worked. I tried to find the locations in the library to change the pins to the pins I have in my microcontroller, but I didn't find it.
The latest error I stumbled over is the following:
I was the output from the serial monitor, and I decoded it:
Exception (9):
epc1=0x402028db epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000003 depc=0x00000000



stack>>>



ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffe50 end: 3fffffd0 offset: 0150
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee714 3ffee794
3fffffb0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee768 402035ec
3fffffc0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3fffdab0 4010110d
<<<stack<<<
Exception 9: LoadStoreAlignmentCause: Load or store to an unaligned address
PC: 0x402028db:  is in Print::write(char const*) (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266/Print.h:59).
EXCVADDR: 0x00000003
Decoding stack results
0x402035ec: loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp:258
But I think this one is another error, which may be just an error of this specific example program.
